# How integrate FireStore Health Check and Dashboard metrics with our internal Company systems

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-analytics, zabbix, dynatrace

Context: it is my first use of FireStore. I want to use it to push notification status to our Mobile Application. I can see that there is Google Firestore Dashboard under Analytics umbrella. In our company we use mainly three tools for monitoring our applications: Zabbix, Dynatrace and certain internal solution based on Elasticsearch. I need to ntegrate our internal monitoring systems with metrics resulted from our first Firestore project.

What I am looking for: based on personal assumptions:

1) Maybe there might exist either some GET endpoints that a I can connect and poll for information let's say each minute

2) Maybe, following the idea of Database Realtime pushing events accross a long time connection, I can code a Spring Boot application that import Firebase SDK and every day I connect to some specific Firestore endpoint which will push any interested events (eg. delay based on custom logic or dead service)

3) Maybe some plugin I can connect straight to a Kafka hosted in our internal Datacent

4) Some plugin to connect from Firestore/Firebase to either third tools (eg. Zabbix or Dynatrace or Elasticsearch)

5) Some dependency I could import in google-cloud-funtions thiggered from Firestore Healcheck engine in orther to consume some internal end-point posting data

Perhaps there is already some approach universally used for a scenario when you have to connect Firestore to internal monitoring system. I will be highly appreciated if tell me that than I can narrow my googling searchs because I am not finding anything usefull.

Please, it is not part of this question comparing Monitoring approach. It is a very solid fact in our company use internal Dashboards and some custom alerts trigger. I just mentioned the names above to clarify what I mean by internal monitoring tools. The focus on this question is HOW IMPORT/INTEGRATE/OBSERVE/CONSUME Firestore monitoring data. Our internal stack is beyond this question.

Comment: I am wondering why someone suggest to close this question. If you read https://firebase.google.com/support?authuser=0 it points to ask here for support. Note that the example starts also with "How" (copied from this link "Example: "How do I cancel a file upload?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage)  is the Official Documentation for Cloud Monitoring using which you can collect metrics, events, and metadata from Google Cloud Platform products that you can use to create dashboards, charts, and alerts.

Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent "The Cloud Monitoring agent is a collectd-based daemon that gathers system and application metrics from virtual machine instances and sends them to Monitoring. " So it is an agent that collects metrics from Cloud VM and pushes such metrics to Google Monitoring. My question is: is there an agent that collect metrics from Firestore and push its metric data to a third endpoint so I can expose an endpoint in our internal Server that is called from Firestore every time we have some issue? An agent or any other feature pushing from Google to us

Comment: I am aware that asking for an example isn't isn't the best way to ask a question. BTW, I have read a lot for the last week regard how consume/collect/observe/listen metrics from my Firestore and I can't find any "first steps/sample". I found numerous article discussing how monitor the mobile application side. But this isn't my goal. I want to monitor Firestore and I am not interested to monitor for pricing review. I know Elasticsearch is elastic and can threat quite well horizontally growing up. This isn't my issue. I want get a list of my Database Firestore Delays, Throughpu, Exceptions etc