# firebasehosting.googleapis.com/network/active_connections: No such file or directory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, google-cloud-monitoring

According to [firebasedatabase metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firebasedatabase)

```
firebasedatabase
Metrics from Firebase. Launch stages of these metrics: BETA GA

The following metric type names must be prefixed with firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/. That prefix has been omitted from the entries in the table.
```

Follow its guidance I tried reached it from gshell and I got

[image: gshell browser console]

Comment: That is the name of a metric, not a file on your system. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics - Overview: https://cloud.google.com/products/operations

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am aware this is the metric name. Actually it is exactly what I want to do do. Get  alives connection as describe "network/active_connections GA
Connections
GAUGE, INT64, 1
firebase_namespace The number of outstanding connections. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 1800 seconds." Copied from https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firebasedatabase